# Generate and update changelog.md after mvn release:perform

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin

I would like to generate, update changelog.md and commit to Bitbucket repository after mvn release:perform is done.

In angular, it has @semantic-release/git, @semantic-release/commit-analyzer, @semantic-release/release-notes-generator, @semantic-release/npm, @semantic-release/changelog, @semantic-release/exec. Is there anything similar in maven release?

**pom.xml**

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
        <configuration>
           <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
           <checkModificationExcludes>
             <checkModificationExclude>pom.xml</checkModificationExclude>
           </checkModificationExcludes>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>

<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
    <id>release</id>
    <url>https://nexus.../.../release/</url>
  </repository>
</distributionManagement>

<properties>
  <project.scm.id>my-scm-server</project.scm.id>
</properties>

<scm>
  <connection>scm:git:https://user@bitbucket.org/user/comutils.git</connection>
  <developerConnection>scm:git:https://user@bitbucket.org/user/comutils.git</developerConnection>
  <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [maven-semantic-release](https://github.com/conveyal/maven-semantic-release) which will generate release notes using Angular style commit messages for Maven projects in the same way as you would do with npm projects.

The documentation suggests how to publish to Maven Central, but you can save some hassle by [publishing to Github packages](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/publishing-packages/publishing-java-packages-with-maven#publishing-packages-to-github-packages).